# ggplot2: Adjust the legends distance to the x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to shrink the legends distance to the x-axis, but I can't find a way to do it. Is it possible?

Example code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = gear, y = mpg, fill = gear)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ack. The answer given by @AdamBirenbaum doesn't work anymore. `legend.margin` must be specified using `margin()` (as the error message reports).

So now the correct answer should be

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = gear, y = mpg, fill = gear)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",legend.margin=margin(t=-10))
```

See: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.2.1/topics/theme

Answer (score 3):

Just adjust the margin value.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = gear, y = mpg, fill = gear)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",legend.margin=unit(-.05,"cm"))
```