# Move ggplot legend closer to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Below is some code to show plotting of a scatterplot 2 different ways.

The first way gets me exactly what I want to see, but if I were to make it into a template for a whole bunch of scatterplots, I'd still have to play around with the `plot.margin` variable to ensure that the legend is still within the image's margins.

The second uses a different method to get the legend into the position I desire. However, I can't move the legend closer to the plot without messing up the box around the legend, as shown in the third plot taking the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892812/ggplot2-adjust-the-legends-distance-to-the-x-axis) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362895/r-ggplot2-change-the-spacing-between-the-legend-and-the-panel) that obviously doesn't work here. That suggestion moves the text, but not the legends box!

```
library(ggplot2)

data_points = data.frame(x=rnorm(n=16), 
                         y=rnorm(n=16), 
                         col=c(rep("red",8), rep("blue",8)),
                         shap=rep(c(rep("sq",4), rep("tr",4)), 2))

desired_look = theme(plot.margin = margin(r = 25), # I need to play with the margin value or else it will be cut off
                         legend.justification = c("left", "top"),
                         legend.position = c(1,1)
                         #legend.margin = margin(c(1,1,1,3)))

just =   theme(legend.justification = "top") # Way too far away from the plot, how do I get it closer?

just_box_probs =   theme(legend.justification = "top", 
                          legend.box.margin = margin(l = -10)) # text is now outside the box!!!

p = ggplot(data_points, aes(x=x, y=y, color=col, shape=shap)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() +
    scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = NULL)) +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = NULL)) + 
    theme(legend.spacing = unit(0, "pt"), 
          legend.key.height = unit(8, "pt"), 
          legend.spacing.x = unit(1, "pt"), 
          legend.key.width  = unit(0, "pt"), 
          legend.background = element_blank(), 
          legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))

ggsave(filename = "desired_look.png", p + desired_display, width = 2, height = 2)
ggsave(filename = "just.png", p + just, width = 2, height = 2)
ggsave(filename = "just_box_probs.png", p + just_box_probs, width = 2, height = 2)
```

Desired Look:

[image: Desired Look]

Legend is too far from the plot, plot itself is squished:

[image: Just]

Legend box doesn't move with legend text:

[image: Issue with adjusting margins]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
data_points = data.frame(x=rnorm(n=16), 
                         y=rnorm(n=16), 
                         col=c(rep("red",8), rep("blue",8)),
                         shap=rep(c(rep("sq",4), rep("tr",4)), 2))
                     
ggplot(data_points, aes(x=x, y=y, color=col, shape=shap)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = NULL)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = NULL, 
                                         name = NULL,
                                         breaks = NULL)) + 
  theme(legend.spacing = unit(0, "pt"), 
        legend.key.height = unit(8, "pt"), 
        legend.spacing.x = unit(1, "pt"), 
        legend.key.width  = unit(0, "pt"), 
        legend.background = element_blank(), 
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        legend.justification = "top",
        legend.margin=margin(4,4,4,4),
        legend.box.spacing = margin(0.5))
```

[image: example_1.png]

You can change the dimensions of the plot without the relative dimensions changing, e.g.

[image: example_2.png]

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: legend.box.spacing was the solution. Thank you!